# Why does Flutter State object require a Widget?

Tags: dart, flutter

The demo example has the following code, which is apparently typical of Flutter apps:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {...}
}
```

I'm OK, I guess, with `MyHomePage` overriding the `StatefulWidget` `createState` method. It's a little awkward but what the heck? And even depending on a `State` subclass. Fine.

But then having the `State` subclass turn around and depend on `MyHomePage`?! I'm having trouble wrapping my fairly abundant wits around that one.

So perhaps I'm unclear on what `State<MyHomePage>` is/does. With, say, `Map<String, Object>` the meaning is clear: Associate a string with an object. Can someone please elucidate? And if you could include something about the need for a state object to extend a widget, I would enjoy reading that.

Comment: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/build.html

Comment: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State-class.html

Comment: Thanks, Pawan. Nice design discussion in the first doc.

Answer (score 3):

This is to make widget properties access far easier.
When you do

```
new MyStatefulWidget(foo: 42, bar: "string")
```

Then you most likely want to access `foo`/`bar` from your `State`.

Without such syntax you'd have to type custom `State` constructor and pass all `StatefulWidget` subclass properties to `State` subclass inside `createState`. Basically you'd have that:

```
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final int foo;

  MyStatefulWidget({this.foo});

  @override
  MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => MyStatefulWidgetState(foo: foo);
}

class MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  final int foo;

  MyStatefulWidgetState({this.foo});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(

    );
  }
}
```

Boring. You have to write all fields of `StatefulWidget` subclass twice.

---

With the current syntax; you don't have to do this. You can directly access all properties of the currently instantiated widget within `State` by using `widget` field.

```
class MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(widget.foo);
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd be kind of OK with widget subclasses only *containing* state. Why can't we just do that?

Comment: You mean, why is there more than just data here? Why is there `build` and such?

Comment: Must `State` also have `build`?

Comment: The separation of concerns is murky. Conceptually, `State` should be kept distinct from the presentation, or `Widget`.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what `State` means in  Flutter. It's the state of a widget. Not the state of your app. Which is why there is methods such as `didUpdateWidget` or `dispose` on the `State`.

Comment: @TomRussell if you want to store actual application state, `InheritedWidget` is more what you want. And that one doesn't force the "state" to have dependency on the view

Comment: Thanks, Rémi. That's probably right about my misunderstanding `State`. Presumbly, then, Widget state contains stuff about the width of the view, etc.

Comment: But doesn't `StatelessWidget` also manage similar data about the view?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178119/discussion-between-remi-rousselet-and-tom-russell).

Comment: I'd disagree about the point on ease of property access. Generally speaking, there are better ways of achieving property access other than generics.

Answer (score 2):

In Flutter, everything is a widget and there are 2 types of widgets: Stateless and Statefull.

**Stateless:** A widget that does not require mutable state.

**Statefull:** A widget that has ***mutable*** state.

That is why all Statefull widget is dependent of a `State<T>`, because it manages changes (state) in the widget.

Comment: That's not really what he aksed though. He want to know why `State<T>`, why not just `State`